# Select element which is extended popup menu (submenu)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Since couple weeks I'm trying to figure out how can I select (choose) item on popup menu which is extended to another popup submenu. For example:

```
 HMENU hMenu,hSubMenu;
 hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
 hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
 AppendMenu(hMenu , MF_POPUP | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED, (UINT_PTR) hSubMenu, name.c_str()); // this one i want to select and choose on callback
 AppendMenu(hMenu , MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) count, name.c_str());
```

Than I'm trying to get Callback with: `WM_MENUSELECT` to catch the name of hover element. 
But when I click on this hSubMenu element - menu don't want disappear, but is still active and extends submenu elements.

`WM_INITMENUPOPUP` will not help.

I just want to close this popup menu when i get message back from `WM_MENUSELECT`.
`WM_LBUTTONUP` doesn't work on popup menu...

Could You give me some advice? I'm coding with pure winapi.